# ms-access concat a string with control source

Tags: ms-access, errors, syntax

Sorry for this likely noob question but I cannot seem to find the solution. I'm trying to modify an existing field on a report, standard in this field the data is being pulled from the control source `Insert` under the properties pane and looks fine. I'm trying to change this into a 1D barcode which requires `*` before and after. I check the syntax for concating strings with inputs and it should be `= "*" & [Insert] & '*"` but this just throws a `#Type!` error on the report when it's viewed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As the users in the comments above pointed me in the right direction, the issue was a circular reference error between the name of the created field (`TextBox`) and the `Control Source`. These can be viewed in the `Property Sheet` of a form or report under `All` tab. Obviously you don't want to rename the `Control Source` between this references the table or query the data's being pulled from, so just change the name of the text box. For whatever reason MS Access defaults with the names being the same so this is a common issue. In the image, originally the fields `Name` and `Control Source` both contained `Insert`.

[image]